# Parcel configuration to disable css class name mangling

Tags: css, css-modules, parceljs

I have a web app that uses Parcel as the bundler/compiler. I've imported Bootstrap successfully, but Parcel always adds a prefix to the class names regardless of whether it's a CSS module or a file. I frequently use the browser's page inspector to edit the classes & style in place, so I would like to disable the prefix generation (at least for development builds).

Is there a way to do this?